# How to set variables inside an `if` block

Tags: batch-file

I am unable to set the variables inside `if` `else`.

```
@echo off
set cur_date=check
echo %cur_date%     

if "true"=="true" (
  echo 1
  set curs_date=checks
  echo %curs_date%
)
pause
```

In above code, `echo %cur_date%` and `echo 1` are getting printed.
But `echo %curs_date%` is not assigned.

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) (by the way: your variable _is_ set but not shown.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion at the top of your script, and inside the if statement use `!` instead of `%`. See also [this](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/combining-all-mp4s-in-directory-with-ffmpeg/30284028#30284028)